# ADD Total is Greyed Out In SSRS Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to add Totals to at the end for many columns,but when i right click on the box Add Total is Greyed out,How can i enable ADD Totals?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

At the extreme bottom in visual studios you have your groups listed.
Right click on the group name for which you want to add the total. Go to Add Total -> After .
Refer to the image below :[image]

Answer (score 1):

If "Add Total" is greyed out, right click on your package and choose "View Code."
Search for the field you want to total.
In my case this field was defined as

```
<rd:UserDefined>true</rd:UserDefined>
```

even though the underlying datatype was an int.
Replaced this with

```
<rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
```

The "Add Total" option will be enabled.